# The quotient remainder theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have tried understanding how to solve questions of these type using pen and paper, without access to a calculator.

Here's the question:

> What is the remainder of $2019^2 + 2019^4 + 2019^6 + 2019^8$ $mod 4$ ?

I know that there's a pattern to these types of questions, but I am not exactly sure how to find it.

I thought about breaking the numbers into smaller numbers that are congruent to them, but I am not sure if that would be of any help.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;2019=-1\pmod 4\;$ ,we get

$$2019^2+2019^4+2019^6+2019^8=(-1)^2+(-1)^4+(-1)^6+(-1)^9=1+1+1+1=0\pmod4$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it's basically all about trial and error until we find what 2019 is congruent to?

Comment: Well, no: it is just basic arithmetic...and the fact that $\;4\;$ is a pretty small number and it is very easy to know what residue modulo $\;4\;$ any integer is.